# Deleting Strings with random numbers inside

Tags: linux, string, concatenation

What should I do to get the Output below for my report:

I would like to remove the string after the usernames and "]" on it., also the whole string after the name of the person ":/export/home/username:/bin/csh"

```
jdelacruz:x:327[@gmail.com]Juan Dela Cruz:/export/home/jdelacruz:/bin/csh
dquijote:x:304[@yahoo.com]Don Quijote:/export/home/dquijote:/bin/csh
usam:x:314[@live.uk]Uncle Sam:/export/home/usam:/bin/csh
```

*Output:*

```
jdelacruz@gmail.com
dquijote@yahoo.com
usam@live.uk
```

And also how do i the the string after the "]" and before ":/export/home/username:/bin/csh" which is the Full name of the user

```
Juan Dela Cruz
Don Quijote
Uncle Sam
```

---

Another list of accounts save as latestmail.txt

```
jcaole:x:64349:2000:Joanah C. Caole:/export/home/jcaole:/bin/csh
jdantonio:x:64054:2000:Joseph D. Antonio:/export/home/jdantonio:/bin/csh
ljobando:x:65018:2000:Lervin John M. Obando:/export/home/ljobando:/bin/csh
```

Comment: [$ man cut](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut)

Comment: its a textfile in Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you could do it with `awk`:

First, create a text file called `foo.awk`:

```
BEGIN {}
{
    split($0, arr, ":");
    username = arr[1];
    gunk = arr[3];
    match(gunk, /\[(.*?)\]/, gunk_bits);
    print username gunk_bits[1];
}
END {}
```

Let's say you have a text file called `bar.txt`:

```
jdelacruz:x:327[@gmail.com]Juan Dela Cruz:/export/home/jdelacruz:/bin/csh
dquijote:x:304[@yahoo.com]Don Quijote:/export/home/dquijote:/bin/csh
usam:x:314[@live.uk]Uncle Sam:/export/home/usam:/bin/csh
```

You can `awk` it like so:

```
$ awk -f foo.awk bar.txt
jdelacruz@gmail.com
dquijote@yahoo.com
usam@live.uk
```

To get the other stuff, create a text file called `baz.awk`:

```
BEGIN {}
{
    split($0, arr, ":");
    gunk = arr[3];
    match(gunk, /\[(.*?)\](.*?)/, gunk_bits);
    print gunk_bits[2];
}
END {}
```

Then:

```
$ awk -f baz.awk bar.txt
Juan Dela Cruz
Don Quijote
Uncle Sam
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex Reynolds, let my System Admins do this since he have the root password.

Comment: When I used the scripts and run there was an error "awk: syntax error near line 6" even we change it permission to 'chmod +x foo.awk'

Comment: Maybe check the version of `awk` you're using. Works fine here: `$ awk --version \n GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0`